# How to get the songd from sdcard and display it in listview

Tags: android, file, android-sdcard

This is the code I have so far:

```
List<File> dir = new ArrayList<File>();
List<File> files = new ArrayList<File>();

File root = new File (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath());

    scan(root);

    for (File f : dir) {
       scan(f);
    }

public void scan (File path) {

    for (File f : path.listFiles()) {
        if (f.isFile()) {
            files.add(f);
        }
        else {
            dir.add(f);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Any questions or so?

Comment: I am not solved till the problem..I want to create a playlist and load the song from it..

Comment: Also no questions. Ok.